# Apache url rewrite plus sign not working as expected

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, rewrite

I'd like to rewrite my site url of below two patterns (note: there are a lot such urls that i hope to use one rule to rewrite them all)

```
www.hetaoblog.com/hello
www.hetaoblog.com/hello/
```

to

```
**www.hetaoblog.com/myblogs/post/hello.jhtml**
```

all other cases like `http://www.hetaoblog.com/` should not be changed;

I've tried

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  #RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
  RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ /myblogs/post/$1.jhtml [L]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /myblogs/post/$1.jhtml [L]
</IfModule>
```

and

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  #RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
  RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /myblogs/post/$1.jhtml [L]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /myblogs/post/$1.jhtml [L]
</IfModule>
```

and

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)+/$ /myblogs/post/$1.jhtml [L]
```

however, they work for my wanted two cases but they will both rewrite

```
www.hetaoblog.com/
```

to

```
www.hetaoblog.com/myblogs/post/.jhtml
```

It looks the + sign which should mean at least one occurrence is not happening.

Comment: Do you mean your client browser is getting a redirect?  That's what it seems like is happening.  Can you clarify what you're looking to accomplish - you're wanting to "rewrite" to `www.hetaoblog.com/hello.jhtml`, but your rules are pointing to `/myblogs/post/$1.jhtml`?  Are you looking to redirect the client, or transparently serve content from the other location?

Comment: I corrected my statement, i want to rewrite to www.hetaoblog.com/myblogs/post/hello.jhtml;  i did not see a client redirect; the thing is, i only want urls like www.hetaoblog.com/hello and www.hetaoblog.com/hello/ to be rewritten; and keep www.hetaoblog.com/ unchanged; but now i saw in my tomcat that visiting www.hetaoblog.com/ also saw a url rewritten

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ /myblogs/post/$1.jhtml [L]
```

Your `/` is redirecting since your `RewriteCond` lines don't apply to the second rule.

I'm still not sure how you determined how it was rewriting to `/myblogs/post/.jhtml` - that doesn't make sense at all with the rules you have, though.

Wordpress might still be interfering; turn on a `RewriteLog` location and set `RewriteLogLevel 9` so that we can confirm that Apache's behaving properly.

Comment: thx, this works as expected! I put 'JKMount /*.jhtml ajp13' in apache's httpd.conf so that all *.jhtml request will be forward to my tomcat and I print the url in the servlet; btw, could you talk a bit more in detail about why my / is redirecting? i'm still confused. because it looks / is taking place at first rule. thx

Comment: Each `RewriteCond` line only applies to the `RewriteRule` that directly follows it. Normally, the `%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` rule would prevent the subsequent rewrite for happening for `/`, since the `DocumentRoot` is (probably) a directory.  But, that only applies to the first `RewriteRule` - the second pays no attention to the `RewriteCond` lines and simply rewrites if it matches.  Since `^.*$` matches a zero-length string, it rewrites. The rule that I've provided for you avoids the need to make extra copies of the `RewriteCond` lines by handling the effect of both your `RewriteRule`s in one.

Comment: wow, amazing! thx a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest one is:

```
RewriteRule /hello/? /hello.jhtml [L]
```

This will match exactly the two URIs you specified and no others.

Comment: well, the thing is in this way i've to list all my possible pattern in the rewrite rule, which contains hundreds; because it was previously a wordpress blog with link pattern as http://www.hetaoblog.com/%post_name%, as i've many posts, so there are a lot

Comment: Can you describe a common pattern with all the URLs?  Something like `/blog/<number>/<title>` would do.

Comment: current post url are all like /%post_name%/, such as /java-exception-handling/, /hello-world/; and i've other urls like /tool/hourlog.jhtml that will go to my tomcat;  i hope to rewrite post urls to postname.jhtml so i'll let tomcat other than php to handle it

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simply:

```
RewriteRule ^/([A-Za-z0-9]+|[A-Za-z0-9]+/)$ /myblogs/post/$1.jhtml [L]
```

You also might need to specify rewritecond query string.

Comment: thx for help; the thing is i've chinese in the url that such a expression will not satify.